# adding a tab character in swift

Tags: swift, whitespace

how do you add space in swift?i tried print("\t") but swift seems to ignore the spaces.
My code is

```
var b=1
var a=2

for var i=3;i>=0;i--
{
    for var j=a;j>=0;j--
    {
        print("\t")
    }
    a--

    for var one=1;one<=b;one++
    {
        print("1")

    }
    b++
    println(" ")
}
```

Comment: Question makes no sense. Add space to what? Tab is `"\t"` not `"\n"` in any case. And what you see in the _console_ is not a very accurate representation of the string, so it's not a very meaningful way to test. Maybe it would better if you explained what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: At minimum, show us what output you wanted.

Comment: @matt and Daniel sorry i meant "\t" and i want to display a trinagle of 1 and i am using swiftstub

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Answer (score 25):

The question is confusing, but rest assured in Swift 3, this will print a tab:

```
print("\t")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing what you are trying to do based on the question and code... Does this do it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift
for x in 1 ... 4 {
    for y in 0 ..< 4 - x {
        print(" ")
    }
    for y in 0 ..< x {
        print("1")
    }
    print("\n")
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
   1
  11
 111
1111
```

Comment: yes its suppose to but i cant get it to display space even with print(" ")

Comment: Okay, the above code prints out the above output. If the output is what you want, then the code does that. Do you want me to add an explanation as to how the code works?

Comment: latest swift does not permit.  as far as I can find, you have to use unicode values e.g., \\(decimal-number)

Answer (score -11):

in swift 3:

```
print("   1")
print("  11")
print(" 111")
print("1111")
```

the outputs:

```
   1
  11
 111
1111
```